# How to use BigSlide.js with pug template engine?

Tags: javascript, menu, pug

I have big problem with menu using bigslide.js plugin and pug, but with php menu work great.

After included all nesesery files this code on laravel works great:

```
<div id="nav-icon" class="wrap push">
    <a href="#menu" class="menu-link"><span><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span></a>
</div>
<nav id="menu" class="panel" role="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">The Ballad of El Goodo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Thirteen</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">September Gurls</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">What's Going Ahn</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.menu-link').bigSlide();
    });
</script>
```

After convert this code to pug:

```
       #nav-icon.wrap.push
          a.menu-link(href='#menu')
            span
              i.fa.fa-bars
        nav#menu.panel(role='navigation')
          ul
            li
              a(href='#') Home
            li
              a(href='#') The Ballad of El Goodo
            li
              a(href='#') Thirteen
            li
              a(href='#') September Gurls
            li
              a(href='#') What's Going Ahn
        script.
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.menu-link').bigSlide();
            });
```

Menu is empty and nav is outside menu. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get any console errors? What does the Pug code compile to? Try `a(href="#menu" class="menu-link")`

Comment: Console clear, but when click on button to show menu, div nav-icon change own style, but nav id=menu not. If I changed style for it manualy, everythings looks fine

Comment: What is the compiled HTML (from Pug)? Is it identical to the HTML that you're trying to replicate?

Comment: Yes, if compile first block of code from post to PUG get on output second block of code from thist post

Comment: Check your indentation. It looks like `nav#menu` may need to be adjusted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just move pug code to new file and include it in another file where I need menu and now everything work great. Don't know why but it work. Thanks for help :D